# Leer un archivo PHP de otro dominio

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

Tengo un archivo `.php` al cual le paso un parámetro con una orden en `SQL` y me da el resultado en texto por la página.

Ejemplo:  `domain.com/sql_bridge.php?order=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20settings`

Entonces esto me retorna la sentencia, incluso soy capaz de recogerla con `js` desde el mismo dominio.

```
function ask(order="",callback){
  $("<div></div>").load("http://domine/sql_bridge.php?order="+encodeURI(order), function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    callback(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr)
  });
}
```

Lo que me gustaría es poder recoger el resultado del `SQL` desde otro dominio.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Por cuestiones de seguridad, dudo mucho que puedas ejecutar la consulta, a menos que el otro dominio tenga una API que lo permita.